# fzf.vim how to configure the maximum amount of files stored in recent files history?

Tags: plugin-fzf, fzf

Just like the title states. I've read through the readme at https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim but can't seem to see anything mention about this. I've even tried to search the repo for `max` which only returned 1 seemingly unrelated match.

The default seems to be 90 files which seems very small, specially when working with many projects.

By recent file history I mean the files that show up via `:History`.

Comment: Which command are you referring to exactly? I guess `fzf` only looks at an history stored somewhere and the configuration does lies with fzf but with vim itself.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:History` command operates on `:oldfiles` result which is stored in `v:oldfiles` variable that is loaded from `viminfo`.

You can change it by changing `viminfo`, there might be better approach, but anyways:

0. the value to adjust is `'100` (default)
1. check current value with `:set viminfo`  (mine is: `'100,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:`)
2. change `'100` to whatever you want, for example 200: `:set viminfo='200,<50,s10,h,rA:,rB:`